# Rails Authentication and Authorization - Best approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authorization, devise-invitable

I've been battling at how to accomplish this for a while and even started working on different solutions only to notice it's not very practical or could lead to problems.

Scenario: A user can create an Admin account and invite (mail invite) another user as a Client. I was thinking of using the devise_invitable gem to handle the invitation process. I'm not sure if I should have 2 models (Admin/Client).

Gems I've been considering:
devise
devise_invitable
cancancan
pundit
rollify

The thing is that whatever setup I use for authentication and authorization must comply with devise_invitable gem given that its a load of my mind to build that functionality myself.

Comment: Please take a look at the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help), paying special attention to what's [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site and what [questions to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You're soliciting opinions on a broad topic, which doesn't meet the criteria for a "specific programming question or issue" because it's subjective and wide open for debate.

Answer (score 0):

Devise and Oauth 2.0. If you need an admin panel you can use rails_admin or there are a variety of admin gems as well, Or you can make your own.